# What is the FreeBSD equivalent of "read -n"?

Tags: bash, shell, read

My question is based on the following [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786543/linux-pipe-with-multiple-programs-asking-for-user-input).

I am trying to use the `read -n 1 a` solution as given there.
However, FreeBSD gives me a :

```
read: Illegal option -n
```

I don't know how to find out, what the FreeBSD equivalent is.
(Please don't tell me RTFM, I searched but can't find the proper info.

Comment: `read` is a shell builtin.

Comment: The Q&A you linked to is using [`bash(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash) which does support the `-n` option on a `read`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not dependent on your operating system but on your shell.

In `bash` and `ksh93`, `read -n N` will read a specific number (`N`) of characters (or bytes).

Other shells, such as `dash` or `ash` (which serves as `sh` on FreeBSD) and `pdksh` (which is `sh` and `ksh` on OpenBSD), does not have a `read` that has this option. The `tcsh` and `csh` shells on FreeBSD also do not have `read -n`.

Comment: `read -n N` reads only up to N characters from one line only, after backslash processing and returns false unless N characters were read or a full line was read. `ksh93` also reads from only one line, but the N is counted before backslash processing it returns false only if no input is available. They also differ wrt IFS processing. Both have `-N` with again differences in behaviour. There's different treatment of NUL characters or bytes not forming part of valid characters. Use `zsh` and its `read -u0 -k N` if you want something that makes sense.

Comment: `sh` is usually referred to as the `Bourne Shell`. A very nice overview of the ancestry can be seen in [Ash (Almquist Shell) Variants](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/). If the OP would like to learn to write portable scripts it would be wise to write them in `sh` no matter which shell he uses for the commandline

Comment: @Claus. No, `sh` was the Bourne shell up until the mid-90s, it was the Thompson shell before that. Since the mid-90s `sh` is based on a standard (POSIX) specification itself based on a subset of ksh88 (itself derived from the Bourne shell but with many extensions and incompatibilities). `bash`, FreeBSD `sh`, `ksh93` attempt to implement that specification but each have extensions of their own including that `read -n`

Comment: @Stéphane: Disagree. The Thompson Shell was a different beast which just happened to have the same commamd name 'sh'. The Bourne Shell was a replacement. Almquist wrote his shell specifically as a clone of Bourne. And this has evolved into a POSIX standard. If you say '/bin/sh' to a seasoned admin they'll refer to it as a Bourne Shell (because of the ancestry). What you seem to try to explain was mapped out in a nice diagram in the link I provided.

Comment: @Claus, no, the Almquist shell didn't evolve into the POSIX standard. The POSIX shell specification is based on a subset of the Korn shell's language. The Bourne shell is not the Almquist shell, nor the Korn shell, nor the Forsyth shell nor the POSIX shell specification. Except for a few rare exceptions, /bin/sh on modern systems implement the POSIX sh language specification which in addition to having a lot of extensions over that of the Bourne shell is not even backward compatible with it. Saying today that sh == Bourne is at best misleading. You may say that modern sh are _Bourne-like_.

Comment: @Stèphane: Still disagree. You misinterpret what I wrote. Feel free to change the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) which says  "Most Unix-like systems continue to have /bin/sh—which will be the Bourne shell, or a symbolic link or hard link to a compatible shell—even when other shells are used by most users". You arguments are along the lines of those who think that we should call BSD and Linux *Unix-like* at all times (not just when pleasing lawyers). We all do understand that we are not using the actual Bourne shell from 1979.